# How to lock a file on network (in Windows)?

Tags: c#, windows, file-io, filesystems, multiprocessing

I'm having a service (C# service) that runs on multiple computers and share the same file (on a network storage say NAS). I want to make sure that when performing a write operation, I should be able to acquire a lock on the file, write and then unlock it.

How can I lock a file on network, when writing to it ?

Comment: Only one process can write to the file at a time. So let the OS worry about that part.

Comment: The concern here is that the processes, could be running on different machines and not the same.

Comment: did you check this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/a5300fc5-126c-4e33-8ae6-13376031e9fe

Comment: If you open the file with writing access and don't explicitly ask for write sharing, it will automagically open the file exclusively, locking access to it.

Comment: Please be more specific what you mean by "acquire a lock". What do you want this lock to accomplish? Prevent the file from being deleted? Prevent another process from writing to the file? Prevent another process from locking the file?

Comment: No, you can't do that.  Consider using a database.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at

[FileStream.Lock Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.lock) and [FileStream.Unlock Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.unlock)

Comment: Again, these locks guarantee that the files will be safely locked only between the processes on same machine. how about by processes running on different machine ?

Comment: @atVelu: what makes you think those methods don't work for processes running on different machines?